# Find out if ID was auto-incremented in before insert-trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

In MySQL I need to know if it's possible in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to find out if the primary key ID  (NEW.Id) is being automatically generated by the *auto-increment value* or if the ID was *manually* set.

The reason for this is that in my application rows can both be inserted with a set ID OR rely on the auto increment value, but I need to know this.

What is the value of NEW.Id in a before trigger if left empty when inserting a row?
It doesn't seem to be NULL, so is it already set to the current auto increment value?
But how to find out then if this is happening?

***UPDATE:***
It seems the value of the integer-type primary key (NEW.Id) in a BEFORE INSERT trigger is 0  (not NULL!), even when there is no default value set for this column.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? (No idea if it is possible)

Comment: I'm implementing my own sequence solution with a separate table that holds the new sequence values for each table. But I still would like to use the auto-increment feature of MySQL too...

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the trigger over the `AFTER` option, than you will be last returned to ID, if you put the trigger on the `BEFORE` option, the action performed will give you zero value because no have a any value.